# References on "Measure and Integration: History and Development"

Tags: reference-request

I would like to get references for **Measure and Integration"**, since I want to study the subject from historical perspective.

The references could be books, articles or the online resources.

Comment: I would recommend Folland, real analysis. But I do not understand your saying "from historical perspective" so I don't know if you'll get what you are searching in it. It is a math book

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a very nice book by Thomas Hawkins titled "Lebesgue's Theory of Integration: Its Origins and Development" [See [this link](http://www.ams.org/bookstore-getitem/item=CHEL-282-H)]. It starts with the 18th century concept of a function and ends with Radon's work on the Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral in the early 20th century. Quite nice, IMHO.

Comment: This is a very good suggestion.